# Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here's my R code. I'm not really sure what I'm doing but I keep getting this error. I'm trying to knit it in RMarkdown and it's not working so if you could help that would be great!!

```
read.table("jmen.txt")
```

```
jmen <- read.table("jmen.txt")
```

### Imitation Graph

```
hair_table<-table(jmen$Hair)
barplot(hair_table, col=c("Black","cornsilk","Salmon4","Coral1"), main="Hair Color of Sampled JMen", xlab="Hair Colors", ylab="Number of Men", names.arg=c("Black","Blond(e)","Brown","Red"))
```

my error is Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

from what I've read it sounds like I need to change my limits from characters to numeric values or something like that? I'm not really sure.

Here's the data for my jmen.txt file

| Name | Age | Eyes | Hair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 32 | Blue | Brown |
| Jim | 39 | Green | Red |
| Jamal | 48 | Brown | Blond |
| Johan | 21 | Blue | Blond |
| Julio | 50 | Green | Brown |
| Julian | 9 | Brown | Brown |
| Jabril | 83 | Blue | Black |
| Jamie | 10 | Brown | Red |
| Joachim | 12 | Blue | Brown |

Name    Age Eyes    Hair
John    32  Blue    Brown
Jim     39  Green   Red
Jamal   48  Brown   Blond
Johan   21  Blue    Blond
Julio   50  Green   Brown
Julian  9   Brown   Brown
Jabril  83  Blue    Black
Jamie   10  Brown   Red
Joachim 12  Blue    Brown

Comment: Please add some data from your .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arose from the start. You forgot to add `header` argument.

An intermediate output was incorrect:

```
hair_table<-table(jmen$Hair)
< table of extent 0 >
```

Now, it works, as you wanted:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

jmen <- read.table("jmen.txt", header=T)
hair_table <- table(jmen$Hair)

barplot(hair_table, 
        col=c("Black","cornsilk","Salmon4","Coral1"), 
        main="Hair Color of Sampled JMen", 
        xlab="Hair Colors", ylab="Number of Men",
        names.arg=c("Black","Blond(e)","Brown","Red"))
```
````

[image]

**For the future:** before adding some code into RMarkdown, test it into console.

And don't forget about formatting code. Good luck ;)